# Play Flask Video Feed in UWP Application using WebView/Media Source

Tags: flask, win-universal-app

I'm attempting to stream a video feed in a UWP application from a webpage created on another machine using flask. The page loads in MS Edge however when the webView is pointed to the page it gets stuck perpetually on the spinning wheel.

In the appxmanifest I've enabled Private Networks(Client & Server), Internet(Client & Server),
and Internet(Client).

I've also tried loading the page using a media player source pointed at the address which throws an error for an invalid address format.

The source for the webpage that I am attempting to load is the following:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="/video_feed">
  </body>
</html>
```

Any advice on what type of object I should be using to try and display the video feed would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:

Below is the source code and xaml for the page that is attempting to use the webView. Currently the image updates at 20 frames per second but this is likely to increase.

Thanks for your help.

```cs
namespace GroundControl.Views
{
    public sealed partial class CameraPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        DispatcherTimer updateDataTimer;
        private const string DefaultUrl = "http://127.0.0.1";

        private Uri _source; 

        public Uri Source
        {
            get { return _source; }
            set { Set(ref _source, value); }
        }

        private bool _isLoading;

        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get
            {
                return _isLoading;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    IsShowingFailedMessage = false;
                }

                Set(ref _isLoading, value);
                IsLoadingVisibility = value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        private Visibility _isLoadingVisibility;

        public Visibility IsLoadingVisibility
        {
            get { return _isLoadingVisibility; }
            set { Set(ref _isLoadingVisibility, value); }
        }

        private bool _isShowingFailedMessage;

        public bool IsShowingFailedMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return _isShowingFailedMessage;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    IsLoading = false;
                }

                Set(ref _isShowingFailedMessage, value);
                FailedMesageVisibility = value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        private Visibility _failedMesageVisibility;

        public Visibility FailedMesageVisibility
        {
            get { return _failedMesageVisibility; }
            set { Set(ref _failedMesageVisibility, value); }
        }

        private void OnNavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            IsLoading = false;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBackEnabled));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsForwardEnabled));
        }

        private void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, WebViewNavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Use `e.WebErrorStatus` to vary the displayed message based on the error reason
            IsShowingFailedMessage = true;
        }

        private void OnRetry(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsShowingFailedMessage = false;
            IsLoading = true;

            webView.Refresh();
        }
        
        private async void OnOpenInBrowser(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(webView.Source);
        }

        public CameraPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IsLoading = true;

            Source = new Uri("http://192.168.1.100:5004");

        }
        
                public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(storage, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

```xml
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:behaviors="using:GroundControl.Behaviors"
    xmlns:Custom="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    x:Class="GroundControl.Views.CameraPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="BrowserButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Page.Style>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PageStyle"/>
    </Page.Style>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <WebView x:Name="webView" Source="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay, Path=Source}"
                 NavigationCompleted="OnNavigationCompleted"
                 NavigationFailed="OnNavigationFailed" />

        <StackPanel Visibility="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay, Path=IsLoadingVisibility}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ProgressRing IsActive="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay, Path=IsLoading}" />
            <TextBlock x:Uid="Camera_Loading" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Visibility="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay, Path=FailedMesageVisibility}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Uid="Camera_FailedMessage" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
            <HyperlinkButton Click="OnRetry" x:Uid="Camera_Retry" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlChromeHighAcrylicElementMediumBrush}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button IsEnabled="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay, Path=IsBackEnabled}" Style="{StaticResource BrowserButtonStyle}" Click="OnGoBack" x:Uid="Camera_BrowserBackButton">
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE72B;" />
                </Button>
                <Button IsEnabled="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay, Path=IsForwardEnabled}" Style="{StaticResource BrowserButtonStyle}" Click="OnGoForward" x:Uid="Camera_BrowserForwardButton">
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE72A;" />
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource BrowserButtonStyle}" Click="OnRefresh" x:Uid="Camera_RefreshBrowserButton">
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE72C;" />
                </Button>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource BrowserButtonStyle}" Click="OnOpenInBrowser" x:Uid="Camera_OpenInBrowserButton">
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE774;" />
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Custom:AdaptiveGridView x:Name="adaptiveGridView">
            <StackPanel BorderBrush="Transparent" Height="370" Width="120">
                <TextBlock x:Name="BatteryLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Battery: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="LatitudeLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Latitude: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="LongitudeLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Longitude: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="AbsAltitudeLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="ABS Alt: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="RelAltitudeLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Rel Alt: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="VelNorthLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Vel North: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="VelEastLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Vel East: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="VelForwardLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Vel Forw: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="VelDownLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Vel Down: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="DistanceDownSenseLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="Dist Down: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="YawAngleLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Yaw Angle: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="YawCamAngleLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Yaw Deg: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="PitchCamAngleLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Pitch Deg: " Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Custom:AdaptiveGridView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Could you please share us with the code about how to use a WebView control pointing to the target web page?

Comment: Added requested information.

Comment: You could try to put the code `IsLoading = false;` within a [dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-19041) to let the code be executed on the UI thread. For example: `await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { IsLoading = false; });`

Comment: I tried your suggestion however still the same result. I also tried removing the the loading bar which just resulted in a frozen webView with a refresh button in the center. I'm not sure what improvements were made with webView2 however when I get a chance I may see if that performs better for my flask app. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You could try to add a breakpoint at the OnNavigationCompleted method to view if the method is called when the WebView control’s navigation completes. If the OnNavigationCompleted method is always not called, could you please tell me if the target address could be open and play video in MS Edge normally?

Comment: I added the breakpoint and the method OnNavigationCompleted is never reach. Using MS Edge, I am able to load the web page.